# How to move resized android display on top of the screen

Tags: android, sdk, adb

I have resized my display using

````
```adb shell wm size```
````

Can I somehow move the display from the middle to the top? I have tried using overscan command but its not giving me the result I'm looking for.

[image: resized display]